# Intercapitalization in Standard Sql with exceptions

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have list of strings which are to be inter-capitalized.

So far I did

---

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION INTERCAPS(my_text STRING)

AS (

(

SELECT

STRING_AGG(

CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTR(list, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTR(list, 2))),

' ' ORDER BY placement

)

FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(my_text, ' ')) as list WITH OFFSET placement

)

);

WITH test_data AS (

SELECT '8th avenue' AS my_text 

UNION ALL

SELECT '88 VALLEY Stream JiMMy Lee BRIDGE' AS my_text

UNION ALL 

SELECT "hen And HEN'S ROAD" AS my_text

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'Water of Leith BRIDGE' AS my_text

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'Anne McLean DRIVE' AS my_text

UNION ALL 

SELECT "John O'Groats ROAD" AS my_text

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'Bowlers Creek (MacKenzies) BRIDGE' AS my_text

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'Clutha RIVER (Luggate) BRIDGE - (mini park) Bridge' AS my_text

UNION ALL 

SELECT "Cross ROAD (O'Neill ROAD)" AS my_text

)

//

SELECT my_text, INTERCAPS(my_text) as formatted

FROM test_data

GROUP BY my_text, formatted

;
```

---

Need help in formatting row 3 - row 9 data.

[Current and Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdLlO.png)

**my_text**

8th avenue

88 VALLEY Stream JiMMy Lee BRIDGE

hen And HEN'S ROAD

Water of Leith BRIDGE

Anne McLean DRIVE

John O'Groats ROAD

Bowlers Creek (MacKenzies) BRIDGE

Clutha RIVER (Luggate) BRIDGE - (mini park) Bridge

Cross ROAD (O'Neill ROAD)

**formatted**

8th Avenue

88 Valley Stream Jimmy Lee Bridge

Hen And Hen's Road

Water Of Leith Bridge

Anne Mclean Drive

John O'groats Road

Bowlers Creek (mackenzies) Bridge

Clutha River (luggate) Bridge - (mini Park) Bridge

Cross Road (o'neill Road)

**Expected Output**

```
8th Avenue

88 Valley Stream Jimmy Lee Bridge

Hen and Hen's Road

Water of Leith Bridge

Anne McLean Drive

John O'Groats Road

Bowlers Creek (MacKenzies) Bridge

Clutha River (Luggate) Bridge - (Mini Park) Bridge

Cross Road (O'Neill Road)
```

---

Basic rule:

Starting alphabet & each alphabet after "space" are to be made in uppercase.

However don't want to format conjunction words like "and" / "of". In my data-set McLean & Mclean are unique names so don't want to mix them.

I was thinking of using regexp_replace using

> r'\(.'

to uppercase first letter after ( in formatted

and

> r'Mac.|Mc.'

to uppercase the formatted **only if** regexp_match Mac[A-Z] in original text but couldn't get hang of it.

---

select match from UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL("xyz and McLean and MacKenzies", r'Mac.|Mc.')) as match WITH OFFSET AS position ORDER BY position;

---- Hope this further helps.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Lots of questions here. 1. What are the rules? What makes `And` become `and`, but `hen` become `Hen`? How are we to determine how to add `a` to `McKenzies`? How are we to change the case of `JiMMy` to `Jimmy` but not `McLean` to `Mclean`?

Comment: Basic rule: Starting alphabet & each alphabet after "space" are to be made in uppercase. However don't want to format conjunction words like "and" / "of". In my data-set McLean & Mclean are unique names so don't want to mix them. I was thinking of using regexp_replace for ** r'\(.' ** to uppercase and  ** r'Mac.|Mc.' ** to uppercase only if regexp_match Mac[A-Z] in original text but couldn't get hang of it.   ----  _  select match from UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL("xyz and McLean and MacKenzies", r'Mac.|Mc.')) as match WITH OFFSET AS position ORDER BY position; _ ----   Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you update your question with the information from your last comments? It would be useful for anyone reading your question.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the catch :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Bigquery function to convert the strings to the format you need

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION capitalize(str STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  return str.replace(
      /\\b(?!and\\s|of\\s)\\b\\S+/g,
      function(txt) {
          return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
      }
  );
""";
```

As an example, you can test it with this query

```
Select capitalize(text) from (Select "hen And HEN'S ROAD" as text)
```

You will get the next output

```
Hen and Hen's Road
```

Comment: Thanks ebeltran. +1 for JS function. Having said that, I am not looking to add JS code and I am still struggling with Mac words...

Comment: Could you provide a more specific example for Mac word? It's not clear what is the expected output for this case, also why using the Bigquery function with JS is not valid in your use case?

Comment: When using the string "paul McLean & Mclean" you want to get "Paul McLean & Mclean" ?

Comment: Example- McLean Drive and Mcbeth Lane are two unique entries in my data set so would like to retain the formatting accordingly but capitalize remaining after every space.  Its not that JS is not valid. I have no knowledge of javascript so it gets difficult for me to explain the code used.

Comment: For the string "paul McLean & mclean" expected output is "Paul McLean & Mclean"